# SQL Server - Set column value based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns, `Part1` , `Part2` and `OnePiece`.

`Part1` can be assigned to [1,2,3,4,5].

`Part2` can be assigned to [1,2,3,4].

`OnePiece` it is of type `Bit`.

Both `Part1` and `Part2` can't have the same values and also if `Part1` is 5 then `Part2` can't have a value.

What I am trying to do is to set `OnePiece` to 1 and make sure `Part2` don't accept any value when `Part1` = 5.

How can I do that ?

---

I will clarify more my request.

The column `OnePiece` is a flag and is calculated automatically and is set to 1 if `Part1` = 5, as for `Part2` it can't be set to any value if `Part1` = 5.

The reason is when `Part1` = 5 it means that it is a one-part-product so there is no `Part2` and must not allow any other value.

So that would make it two things I guess; a trigger and a check constraint. I hope that I have offered more details.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do - are you updating your table or trying to add constraints to assure the aforementioned logic?

Comment: Its a constraint. But I don't know what type of constraint is that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a check constraint to forbid values in `Part2` when `OnePiece` is 1 and `Part5` is 5:

```
alter table YourTable add constraint CHK_YourTable
    check (OnePiece <> 1 or Part1 <> 5 or Part2 is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check constraint to assure this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_chk
CHECK (part1 <> part2 -- "Part1 and Part2 can't have the same values"
       AND 
       (part1 <> 5 OR part2 IS NUILL) -- "if Part1 is 5 then Part2 can't have a value"
      );
```

Comment: Apparently, there is something wrong with my table because I got "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint" error.

Comment: Can you share the DDL for your table, including the constraints in already has?

Comment: The problem was the values previously entered; I found a record with Part1 = Part2 which was causing this conflict. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the `OnePiece` column a computed one with this formula:

```
(CONVERT([bit],CASE [Part1] WHEN (5) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END,0))
```

---

For the constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE [AssemblyData]
ADD CONSTRAINT [CHK_AssemblyData]
CHECK  (([Part2]<>(5))
       AND
       ([Part2]<>[Part1])
       AND
       ([Part1]<>(5) OR [Part2] IS NULL))
```

Thanks for every user contributed to answer this question.